# Linear mapping between vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm curious to see if the following mapping is in fact bijective. Let $P(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of all polynomials with real coefficients. Let $f\in P(\mathbb{R})$. Then is
$f(x)\mapsto (x-1)f'(x)+f(x)$ a bijective map?

Comment: You should be explicit about the domain and range. Do you mean a bijection $P(\mathbb R)\rightarrow P(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Yes. It is a linear map between the two spaces of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(t \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^n p_k t^k)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+k) (p_k-p_{k+1}) x^k + (1+n) p_n x^n$ .

Hence if $f(p) = q$, we have $(1+n)p_n = q_n$ and $(1+k)(p_k-p_{k+1})  = q_k$ for $k < n$. This is solved uniquely by $p_n = {1 \over n+1} q_n$ and
$p_k = {1 \over 1+k}q_k +p_{k+1}$ for $k <n$.

**Aside**: To show uniqueness, suppose $r(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n r_k x^k = 0$ for all $x$. Then $r(0) = r_0 = 0$, and by differentiating, we get $r_1 = 0$, etc. Hence if $a =b$, then the corresponding coefficients must equal, that is $a_k = b_k$.

**Alternative**: Here is another way. Pick some $n$, the consider the restriction of $f$ to $P^n(\mathbb{R})$. Clearly the restriction satisfies $f: P^n(\mathbb{R}) \to P^n(\mathbb{R})$, both finite dimensional spaces. Now consider $f(p) = 0$. From above we see that $p_n = 0$ and so $p_k = 0$ for $k<n$ and hence $p=0$. Hence $f$ is invertible (on $P^n(\mathbb{R})$).

Since $n$ was arbitrary, we see that we must have ${\cal R} f = P(\mathbb{R})$, and if $p \in \ker f$, then we must have $p \in P^n(\mathbb{R})$ for some $n$, hence $p = 0$, hence $\ker f = \{0\}$.

Comment: For the aside I know that your showing injectivity, but what are you doing in the first part, surjectivity?

Comment: The first part shows that for any $q$ there exists a unique $p$ such that $f(p) = q$. Well, it actually shows that given the $q_k$, there exists unique $p_k$ such that $f(p)_k = q_k$. Then the aside shows that $a=b$ **iff** $a_k=b_k$, that is $f(p) = q$.

Comment: Alright I understand it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To show it's invertible, solve the appropriate differential equation and choose the constant of integration so that you end up with a polynomial solution.

Comment: Based on my calculations it should be invertible, am I correct? I have already shown it to be surjective, and injectivity I showed by solving the differential equation $g'(x)+\frac{g(x)}{x-1}=0$, where $g(x)=f_1(x)-f_2(x)$. And I ended up getting as my solution $g(x)=0$. Which implies $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$.

Comment: The way I got that differential equation in the first place was assuming that $(x-1)f'_1(x)+f_1(x)=(x-1)f'_2(x)+f_2(x)$.

Comment: @S.Sheng Uniqueness follows from the uniqueness of the constant of integration that yields a polynomial solution to the differential equation.